# Como posso pegar o valor dentro desta <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá. Preciso pegar o valor dentro de uma `<td>` através do seu seletor.

Esta `<td>` contém o valor total de uma compra (dentro de um checkout).

Usando o console:

```
document.querySelector(".monetary")
```

neste caso consigo pegar o elemento:

```
<td class="monetary" data-bind="text: totalLabel">R$ 75,22</td>
```

porém preciso pegar o valor 75,22 isolado.

Como devo proceder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De modo geral para capturares conteúdo numa string podes usar [expressões regulares](https://regex101.com/r/gF4eG7/1). Neste caso: `'R$ 75,22'.match(/\d+,\d+/)` daria `["75,22"]`.

Em expressões regulares o `\d` significa dígito, o `+` significa *1 ou mais* do seletor anterior.

Para aplicar no teu caso podes fazer assim:

```
var td = document.querySelector(".monetary");
var preco = td.innerHTML.match(/\d+,\d+/)[0];
```

**Exemplo:** https://jsfiddle.net/3cxooxss/

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionando...

Answer (score 0):

Com jQuery você pode fazer desta forma:

```
var valorTd = $(".monetary").text(); // retorna R$ 75,22
var valorMonetario = valorTd.replace("R$ ", ""); // retorna 75,22
```

Comment: Valeu obrigado...funcionando blz.